# Menu text align in css + html

Tags: css, menu, text-alignment

I am getting mad with this problem. Mi website has a menu, and it looks well in the index. You can see it here: 
http://www.farmaciagimeno.com

But when I enter to see a product (with a browser other than Firefox), the menu items align to the top of the menu, like this:

[image]

You can see this effect here:

http://www.farmaciagimeno.com/promociones/superofertas

I have tried modifying several things in the css but cannot find where the problem is.
Can you css gurus give me a hand?
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: block;` from `#menu > ul > li > a`

Comment: thank you! that was it. When I tried to inspect the element, this property didn't appear, as if it wasn't in the css...why is that?

Comment: Strange... Both in Firefox as in Chrome this class appeared to me.

Answer (score 1):

remove height and display:block from a, set your line-height if not yet.